# Python shell in debugger after opening a python core dump

Tags: python, gdb, coredump

I have a core dump of a running CPython program and would like to execute Python code in the dumped process's context.

I have loaded the core and the interpreter into gdb with `gdb python core-dump-file`.

I know about `python-interactive`, but it isn't able to see the context (ex: `import sys; sys.modules` doesn't give me any of the process's modules)

How can I do this?

I don't mind calling CPython's C functions if that is the only possible way.

Answer (score -1):

1) First check if your gdb has been built with python from source.

You can do this(in the gdb prompt) by:

```
(gdb) python print("Hi from python")
```

If you want to check the version of python in your system try:

```
(gdb) python import sys
(gdb) python print(sys.version)
```

If these commands fail. It probably means that your gdb was never built with python support in the first place.

You should build gdb from source, and in the configure step add --with-python="Path to python"

eg.

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python36
```

Hope this helps!!